# How do I find the controller which is providing the data for an Xcart smarty template

Tags: smarty, x-cart

One of my big problems is discovering where the data is generated from. I can skin a template fine but when it comes to changing the supplied data for example the breadcrumbs I havn't got a clue where to look.

Is there an easy method for figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

All your template variables assigned in **Modules** Directory in X-cart